# Multiple finally clauses

Tags: scala

Assume you have two different objects requiring cleanup after execution using a call to method `cleanup()`. I would do this using a `try-finally` construct.

```
val objA = new ObjA()
val objB = new ObjB()
try {
  // do failure prone important stuff
} finally {
  objA.cleanup()
  objB.cleanup()
}
```

However, the cleanup function might also throw an exception. **Is there a more elegant way of solving this than having another `try-finally` in the `finally` block?**

```
// cluttering working solution:
val objA = new ObjA()
val objB = new ObjB()
try {
  // do failure prone important stuff
} finally {
  try {
     objA.cleanup()
  } finally {
     objB.cleanup()  
  }
}

// Is there an option to do something more readable like:

try {
  //do failure prone important stuff
} finally {
  objA.cleanup()
} finally {
  objB.cleanup()
}
```

I concede that having a cleanup function that may throw exceptions breaks the contract of a cleanup function. However, you do not always control external APIs.

Comment: Use [`Using` from the **stdlib**](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/Using$.html) or even better [`Resource` from **cats-effect**](https://typelevel.org/cats-effect/docs/std/resource).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using `scala.util.Try` to wrap the cleanup calls ?

```
import scala.util.Try

try {
  // do failure prone important stuff
} finally {
  Try(objA.cleanup())
  Try(objB.cleanup())
}
```

Comment: This will not clean up objA if objB's constructor throws an exception. Hence Duduk's solution is preferable.

Answer (score 0):

How about this - two blocks, outer dealing with objA, inner dealing with objB, and exceptions, no matter where they get thrown ('important stuff' or any of two cleanup calls), can be caught 'outside' of both of them:

```
  val objA = new ObjA()
  try {
    val objB = new ObjB()
    try {
      // do failure prone important stuff
    } finally {
      objB.cleanup()
    }
  } finally {
    objA.cleanup()
  }
```

Comment: How is this any different from what OP's original problem was ?

Comment: It cleans up objA even if objB's constructor throws an exception.